# Is it required to have both ATS/ACTS and AMF in electrical system?

Tags: power, switches, generator, system

I just read an electrical system layout and specification, where the designer put an ACTS on the distribution panel (to switch between the main and generator), and AMF on the generator. What I read online is: ACTS and AMF serve the same function. So, why should there be both in a system?
I know my question sounds stupid, but I'm not an electrical engineer.

And the follow up to that question is: what influences the start-up time of a generator set, is it ACTS that define it or is it AMF?
I'm sorry if my questions seem incongruent, there is a background to that that will be quite boring to explain.

Comment: Welcome! What's ACTS and AMF?

Comment: ACTS= Automatic Control Transfer Switch

AMF = Automatic Mains Failure


I looked up online about the difference and they say its basically the same thing, and I got even more confused.